# Strange behavior with commands.Cog.listener() function

Tags: python, discord.py

The purpose of this function is to check if a certain value (the message.guild.id) is inside another value located in a dictionary, and if so, return another value, a list of string words. Then, check if a word in the message.content is located in returned string list of words.

Code:

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author.bot:
            return
        
        bwl = GetWF(message.guild.id) #get banned words for given server if they exist
        print(type(bwl))
        print(bwl)
        if bwl is not None:
            xxx = " ".join(str(i) for i in bwl)
            xxx2 = xxx.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
            print(xxx2)
            #print(type(xxx))
            try:
                for word in ' '.join(x for x in xxx2): #for words in banned list
                    if word in message.content:
                        await message.delete() 
                        await message.channel.send(f"`HEY {message.author.name}!\nThat word is banned!`")

                    else:
                        return 

            except Exception as e:
                return 
        else:
            print("bw not found")
            pass

        await client.process_commands(message)
```

It almost does, what I want it to.
But, let's say that the returned list is: 'cat', 'dog', 'mouse'
If I were to say mouse, it wouldnt work, if I were to say 'dog' it would work. But even if I say a word that is not located in the list, it works.
For example:
'dog' would be detected and deleted
but
'noob' would also be detected and deleted even tho 'noob' is not in the dictionary.
How do I make it do exactly what I want it to do, which is see if word is in the dict, and if it is, delete word.

Tried the code and I expected the correct result, but alas, no

Answer (score 1):

Do the check like this, this will fix your problem:

```
            if any(word in bwl for word in message.content.split()):
                #try:
                    await message.delete() 
                    await message.channel.send(f"`HEY {message.author.name}!\nThat word is banned!`")
                #except Exception as e:
                #    pass
```

Usually you don't want to blindly ignore and hide any Exception, so I commented out that part. If you are sure that you need it, then uncomment it.

Here is how it works:

- `bwl` is a list of strings.
- `message.content` is a string.
- `message.content.split()` is a list of strings, which we get from `message.content` by splitting on whitespace.
- To check that these two lists have any common elements, we use `any(word in bwl for word in message.content.split())`.

To get better (more lenient) matches, you may want to do some preprocessing:

```
bwl = set(word.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').lower()
          for word in bwl)
```

, and also convert `message.content` to lowercase when matching:

```
            if any(word in bwl for word in message.content.lower().split()):
```

Please note that your check is still too strict, for example if the user says `mouse!` (with the exclamation mark), then it won't be matched. Also the word `mice` won't be matched. Also the word `dogs` won't be matched. Also the word `tomcat` won't be matched. You may want to ask separate questions on StackOverflow.com to get these matched as well.

Please note that your function looks like very slow and wasteful of network bandwidth, because it retrieves `bwl` from the server for each message. To fix this, initialize `bwl` outside this function.

Comment: If the user says mouse! how could i get that to be detected

Comment: As I said, ask a separate question about that on StackOverflow.com. This answer covers everything you asked originally. You may want to formally accept this answer, because it solves your original problem